# Duplicate a function's type minus the first argument

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, vuex

### The situation

I currently have a function with a signature

```js
type func1= (context: ActionContext<ModuleState, RootState>, id: string): Promise<void>
```

I have many functions that look something like

```js
type commonType = (context: ActionContext<SomeState, RootState>, arg2: arg2Type, arg3?: arg3Type, etc...): Promise<returnType>;
```

Where `SomeState`, `arg*Type`, and `returnType` could be anything

### What I want

I need a way to take a function like `func1`, and export a type with the `context` removed.  So

```js
export type exportedFunc1Type = (id: string) => Promise<void>
```

And to export similar types for other similar functions.

### Attempts

My first attempt was to do

```js
export type ActionType<A extends (context: ActionContext<any, RootState>, ...args) => any > =
  Parameters<A>.slice(1) => ReturnType<A>;
```

But this doesn't work for two reasons:

1. Parameters.slice(1) is not valid.  Question: How can I use array operations besides basic `[n]` on "type arrays"?
2. Even if 1. was solved, `[a,b] => C` isn't valid syntax.  It needs to be `(a,b)=>C` obviously.  Q: How can I convert `[a: typeA, b: TypeB]` to `(a: typeA, b: TypeB)=>C`

After I get that code block working, I could then do

```js
export type exportedFunc1Type = ActionType<typeof func1>
```